# При изменении одного элемента массива перезаписывается весь

Tags: javascript, node.js

В классе есть метод:

```
constructor(id) {
  this.position = [6, 4];
  this.LABYRINTH = init2DArray(8, 8, {lookaround: false, events: false});
  this.lookedaround.bind(this);
}

lookedaround() {
  //this.position задан в конструкторе: this.position = [6, 4];
  this.LABYRINTH[this.position[0]][this.position[1]].lookaround = true;
}
```

Функция заполнения чистого массива:

```
function init2DArray(xlen, ylen, data) {
  var ret = [];
  for (var x = 0; x < xlen; x++) {
    ret[x] = [];
    for (var y = 0; y < ylen; y++) {
      ret[x][y] = data;
    }
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Когда я просто вызываю метод `lookedaround` перезаписывается весь массив целиком заменяя каждое значение на `true`. Я никак не могу понять почему это происходит...

Так есть:

```js
player.LABYRINTH.forEach((e, o) => {
  e.forEach((i, p) => {
    console.log(`[${o}, ${p}] = ${i.lookaround}`);
  });
});
[0, 0] = false
[0, 1] = false
[0, 2] = false
[0, 3] = false
[0, 4] = false
[0, 5] = false
[0, 6] = false
[0, 7] = false
[1, 0] = false
[1, 1] = false
[1, 2] = false
[1, 3] = false
[1, 4] = false
[1, 5] = false
[1, 6] = false
[1, 7] = false
[2, 0] = false
[2, 1] = false
[2, 2] = false
[2, 3] = false
[2, 4] = false
[2, 5] = false
[2, 6] = false
[2, 7] = false
[3, 0] = false
[3, 1] = false
[3, 2] = false
[3, 3] = false
[3, 4] = false
[3, 5] = false
[3, 6] = false
[3, 7] = false
[4, 0] = false
[4, 1] = false
[4, 2] = false
[4, 3] = false
[4, 4] = false
[4, 5] = false
[4, 6] = false
[4, 7] = false
[5, 0] = false
[5, 1] = false
[5, 2] = false
[5, 3] = false
[5, 4] = false
[5, 5] = false
[5, 6] = false
[5, 7] = false
[6, 0] = false
[6, 1] = false
[6, 2] = false
[6, 3] = false
[6, 4] = false
[6, 5] = false
[6, 6] = false
[6, 7] = false
[7, 0] = false
[7, 1] = false
[7, 2] = false
[7, 3] = false
[7, 4] = false
[7, 5] = false
[7, 6] = false
[7, 7] = false

player.lookedaround();

player.LABYRINTH.forEach((e, o) => {
  e.forEach((i, p) => {
    console.log(`[${o}, ${p}] = ${i.lookaround}`);
  });
});
[0, 0] = true
[0, 1] = true
[0, 2] = true
[0, 3] = true
[0, 4] = true
[0, 5] = true
[0, 6] = true
[0, 7] = true
[1, 0] = true
[1, 1] = true
[1, 2] = true
[1, 3] = true
[1, 4] = true
[1, 5] = true
[1, 6] = true
[1, 7] = true
[2, 0] = true
[2, 1] = true
[2, 2] = true
[2, 3] = true
[2, 4] = true
[2, 5] = true
[2, 6] = true
[2, 7] = true
[3, 0] = true
[3, 1] = true
[3, 2] = true
[3, 3] = true
[3, 4] = true
[3, 5] = true
[3, 6] = true
[3, 7] = true
[4, 0] = true
[4, 1] = true
[4, 2] = true
[4, 3] = true
[4, 4] = true
[4, 5] = true
[4, 6] = true
[4, 7] = true
[5, 0] = true
[5, 1] = true
[5, 2] = true
[5, 3] = true
[5, 4] = true
[5, 5] = true
[5, 6] = true
[5, 7] = true
[6, 0] = true
[6, 1] = true
[6, 2] = true
[6, 3] = true
[6, 4] = true
[6, 5] = true
[6, 6] = true
[6, 7] = true
[7, 0] = true
[7, 1] = true
[7, 2] = true
[7, 3] = true
[7, 4] = true
[7, 5] = true
[7, 6] = true
[7, 7] = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что все элементы массива - ссылка на один и тот же объект.

```
function init2DArray(xlen, ylen, dataCreator) {
  var ret = [];
  for (var x = 0; x < xlen; x++) {
    ret[x] = [];
    for (var y = 0; y < ylen; y++) {
      ret[x][y] = dataCreator();
    }
  }
  return ret;
}

this.LABYRINTH = init2DArray(8, 8, function() {
  return { lookaround: false, events: false };
});
```

Comment: Спасибо. Сколько раз попадался на эту проблему с референсами все никак не научусь.